# Code for multiple sums

Tags: summation

Please consider the following code.  The definition of f depends on the code [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/zBpShTJ-OJ8) and works correctly on its own.  The trouble arises when calling `F` (which uses `f`). For some reason, `F` doesn't allow the `K` parameter within `f` to loop as required.  As an example, `f[3, {1, 1, 2, 1}]` gives `a^3 b`, but `F[4, 3, 2]` gives a long expression in `K` & `i` (at least in Mathematica version 12.0).  What please is wrong?  Thank you!

```
f[n_, v_] := (i = Length[v];
  Product[
   If[K < i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, K}] < K - n + 1, 0,
    If[K < i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, K}] >= K - n + 1, a,
     If[K == i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, i}] < i - n + 1, 0,
      b]]],
   {K, 1, i}])

F[i_, n_, m_] := 
 Apply[Sum, 
  Prepend[Table[{j[k], m}, {k, i}], 
   Apply[f, {n, Table[j[k], {k, i}]}]]]
```

P.S.  I am using the code suggested by Steve Luttrell for the definition of `f`.  Conceivably something is wrong with my definition of `F`, which doesn't seem to recognize either `K` or `i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the original functions confusingly written (e.g. the nested `If[]`s), so I rewrote to the following:

```
f[n_, v_] := With[{i = Length[v]},
  Product[Which[
          (K < i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, K}] < K - n + 1) ||
          (K == i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, i}] < i - n + 1),
          0,
          K < i && Sum[Indexed[v, r], {r, 1, K}] >= K - n + 1,
          a,
          True, b],
          {K, 1, i}]]
```

With that,

```
With[{i = 4, n = 3, m = 2}, 
     Sum[f[n, Array[j, i]], 
         Evaluate @ Apply[Sequence, Table[{j[k], m}, {k, i}]]]]
   16 a^3 b
```

Comment: How would the final code block change if I wish instead for each element of j to satisfy j>=0 (rather than j>=1)?  I had mistakenly thought this change would be simple.  Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then the `Table[{j[k], m}, {k, i}]` is actually shorthand for `Table[{j[k], 1, m}, {k, i}]`, which means you should change it to `Table[{j[k], 0, m}, {k, i}]` for your new criterion.

Comment: I see: the change for j-elements affects only the Table part, not the Array part.  Excellent!  You are very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying your code a bit:

```
f[n_, v_] := Module[{i = Length[v]},
               If[Min[Accumulate[v] - Range[i]] < 1 - n, 0, a^(i - 1) b]]

F[i_, n_, m_] := Total[f[n, #] & /@ Tuples[Range[m], i]]

F[4, 3, 2]
(*    16 a^3 b    *)
```

Simplifying even further: all terms coming from `f` have the same form and we can write

```
F[i_, n_, m_] := a^(i - 1) b *
                 Count[Tuples[Range[m], i], 
                       v_ /; Min[Accumulate[v] - Range[i]] >= 1 - n]

F[4, 3, 2]
(*    16 a^3 b    *)

F[4, 0, 2]
(*    8 a^3 b    *)

F[4, -1, 2]
(*    0    *)

Table[F[6, n, 8], {n, -8, 3}]
(*    {0, 0, 32768 a^5 b, 65536 a^5 b, 98304 a^5 b, 131072 a^5 b,
       163840 a^5 b, 196608 a^5 b, 229376 a^5 b, 262144 a^5 b,
       262144 a^5 b, 262144 a^5 b}    *)
```